# How to get physical path for local IIS app with port?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, iis-express

I have hosted some application on my local IIS. One with name (like localhost/app), other (localhost:2222). In my very old project I have set API's url(in web.config) set as localhost:2222, I don't remember where is code for it. I look for physical path.

My question is how to determine from PowerShell or in other way where is physical path for localhost:2222 (with specified port number)?.

Comment: what have you tried? have some code?

Comment: Did you already check out [Web Administration cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=win10-ps)?